# How can I transfer a domain from Squarespace to another registrar?

Tags: dns, domain-registrar, dns-servers, squarespace

I have a client with a domain registered at Squarespace. The website has been migrated elsewhere, but now I am stuck trying to transfer the domain.

I am specifically using Namecheap as my domain host, if that makes a difference. Using their transfer tool, I discovered that the domain is "locked", and that it is actually registered with tucows.

There are no options inside Squarespace that I have found that allow for domain transfer out, just in.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions on the Squarespace site? https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812338-Transferring-a-domain-away-from-Squarespace

Answer (score 1):

The domain "locking" you mention doesn't mean it's locked in the way you're thinking about it. To simplify, it's basically just a security feature that most all services provide so some random person/hacker doesn't essentially 'steal' your domain and transfer ownership to themselves and/or to another site.

SquareSpace is your host (where your website files are stored), and NameCheap is your registrar (where your domain is stored). Every domain has what's called "name servers" that tell people's computers where to look to get the contents of your website. Currently, your domains nameservers, controlled over at Namecheap, are pointed to SquareSpace. Think of having name servers like a mailing address, and your house as the host / Squarespace.

So, all you need to do is log into Namecheap (your registrar), and do the find your domain (usually on the left), and click manage next to the domain you want to edit, and under "name servers" just put in the new address of your new host (they'll look something like 'NS21.DOMAINCONTROL.COM' or some sort of variety of it).

You'll need your name servers at your new hosting company first though to be able to type those in and those are usually provided in an email when you sign up for hosting at most places.

Update: If you're looking to transfer your registrar which is SquareSpace to somewhere else, know that you have to wait 60 days after registering a new domain and the transfer process can take a week.

After that, the process is similar for most places, but with SquareSpace you can go to:
Settings -> Domains -> Uncheck Domain Locking to unloock the domain -> Click Get Transfer Key and copy that code down. Now you can go to NameCheap and transfer in that domain by Changing Ownership there.

Hope this helps, and let me know in the comments if any part seems confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It doesn't actually address my issue, however. My domain is NOT registered with namecheap, it's registered with squarespace. I want to transfer the domain ownership to namecheap, at which point, yes, I can then put in whatever nameservers/DNS records I want.

Comment: @bronzehedwick "I want to transfer the domain ownership" - To clarify, you don't want to transfer _ownership_, you are wanting to transfer the domain to a different _registrar_ (as you state in your question). The _owner_ should be your client.

Comment: @bronzehedwick - I think I misunderstood a bit where you were having trouble exactly. I updated my answer, which I think should be helpful. Please let me know.